# Getting Classdefnotfound exception after adding maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I have a web application for which I have added maven dependency for a jar file. (The jar file added is also a maven project having dependency.) Post adding the mvn dependency I am getting Classnotfoundexception.
Illustration-

[Web appA]-->mvn dependency of x.jar

X.jar --> mvn dependency of y.jar

Classnotfoundexception thrown for A.class present in y.jar.

Please suggest any resolution for this issue.

[Pom.xml of Web-Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ8oH.png)

[Pom.xml of x.jar having dependency of y.jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKrpl.png)

Comment: Please add the POM of your project and that of X to the question.

Comment: Added pom.xml images.

Comment: Please, not images, copy the text.